# expected color not showing on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

the vector color is set to white but when I added it on my floating button, the vector icon is black colored.

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/default_activity_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
       android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add"
       app:backgroundTint="@null"/>
```

```
<vector android:height="50dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
android:width="50dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe by black you mean what this line does: `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `app:tint ="#ffffff"` will help you change the icon color.